# determine/improve excel opening time

Tags: vsto

I have an add-in (actualy 2 one for 2003 and one for 2007). I have been receiving some complains that the office product is opening slower when my add-in is installed.

Is there a way to improve the opening of office product?

Is there a way to compare the opening of the office product with/without the addin

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the how your addin is loaded by the host office app & enforce assorted types of [delayed load](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/04/19/delay-loading-the-clr-in-office-add-ins.aspx).

Comment: I wish i could do that but my addin contains some buttons that are enabled/visible based on some conditions. So i have to load the addin at startup